# Laravel API: validate doesn't access the PUT request data in my API

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, put, laravel-api

## Context

I am implementing a user information update using a `PUT` request in Laravel 8. I use Postman to send the request and see the results.

## Expected behavior

My `PUT` request reaches the controller's function that is censed to update the authenticated user. The latter is updated successfully. So the `validate` call is executed succesfully and finds the data in the request.

## Actual behavior

My `PUT` request reaches the controller's function that is censed to update the authenticated user. The latter is not updated successfully. In fact, the `validate` call is executed succesfully but doesn't find the data in the request.

Instead, data validation says:

> {
> "message": "The given data was invalid.",
> "errors": {
> "email": [
> "The email field is required."
> ],
> "name": [
> "The name field is required."
> ]
> }
> }

## The route & The request

### Postman request

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://XYZ/api/set_user_data' \
--header 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 12|leRLA5yopCLIxe0oN9MMThctqD78iJDjZdZQkcgs' \
--data-urlencode 'email=XYZ@XYZ.FR' \
--data-urlencode 'name=test2'
```

It means in Postman terminology that no "Params" are sent, an Authorization Bearer token is sent, some Headers are sent and some Body's x-www-form-urlencoded data are sent.

### API Route

In `routes/api.php`:

`Route::put('/set_user_data', [UserController::class, 'setUserData'])->name('set_user_data');`

`UserController::setUserData`:

```
public function setUserData(Request $request) {
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return 'unauthenticated.';
    }

    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'name' => 'required|string'
    ]);

 // ... update user here but out of topic
}
```

## What I tried to do... or to *not* do

- Some Stackoverflow answers are: send a `POST` request and send in the body `_method=PUT`. I don't want to do this. I really prefer to send a `PUT` request. Because I am developing an API. It totally justifies the fact that I **must** use a `PUT` request and not a `PUT` one.
- Some Stackoverflow answers are:  use `x-www-form-urlencoded` not a simple `form`. It doesn't fix the problem; moreover it's already the case. Maybe it could help with images sending. (notice I don't want to send any image here).

## Question

Why Laravel's `validate` don't find the data of my request and how to fix it?

Comment: you need to send a valid JSON request. Laravel only requires method PUT on the web requests, not on API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the request as `"Content-type: application/json"`, but you are not sending the body as valid JSON.

You are sending this:`email=XYZ@XYZ.FR&name=test2`

You should send this:

`{"email":"XYZ@XYZ.FR", "name": "test2"}`

a valid JSON object

Comment: You think it's why `validate` doesn't execute?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler i think `validate` is executing, it is just not seeing the data because of the body sent not as JSON

Comment: You are right ty! And if one day I needed to send an image using json, for example I could send the base64 version?

Comment: For those who want to know how I send the `PUT` request with JSON data in Postman, well I just click on "Body" then "raw" then I selected "JSON" and I've written the data at JSON format.